# Capitalize first word in each line of text

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, css-selectors

In a paragraph where words are wrapped to the next line due to word break, what could be a way to capitalize the first word of each line?

Two line example:
**Lorem ipsum and

Prometheus**

Four line example:
**Lorem

Ipsum

And

Prometheus**

I know about the `::first-letter`, `::first-line` selectors but none would be suitable for this case.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to achieve that with current CSS.

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons, but TBH, this would be terrible UX (IMO).

Comment: You can't select the first letter of each break

Comment: You’d need some JS to gradually put the text into the element one ch at a time and notice when its height increases. Would have to be done whenever a change is made, eg viewport resize.

Comment: I only see a JavaScript solution here. Your currently given examples don't _need_ `word-break: break-word`, so if each individual (_not_ breaking) word was wrapped into a span of its own, you could loop over those, and check their `offsetLeft` - if that is currently 0, then this element would need to get a class added, to make the first letter uppercase. Of course you would need to re-run this when any relevant changes to the container width occur, or when the content itself gets modified. [...]

Comment: [...] Throwing `word-break: break-word` into the mix makes it even more complex, because then you would have to have each individual _character_ wrapped into an element of its own, because breaks can occur in _any_ arbitrary position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the text so each word is in its own `span`, then check the `position` of each `span` every time the page resizes.

This may not perform well, so you would likely want to `debounce` the resize.

To make use of `::first-letter` the element must be a block-level element, which `span`, by default, is not.  So it must be `display:inline-block`.

This doesn't handle 'break-word' as OPs samples do not include that as an example and [`break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) is deprecated.

```js
// wrap each word in a span
$("p").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().split(" ").map(t => "<span>" + t + "</span>").join(" "));
});

// determine what is "left" (it's not 0)
var farLeft = $("p").position().left;

// add a class to each "left" element and let css handle the rest
function firstLetter() {
  $(".farleft").removeClass("farleft");
  $("p>span").each(function() {
    if ($(this).position().left == farLeft) {
      $(this).addClass("farleft");
    }
  })
}

$(window).on("resize", firstLetter);
firstLetter();
```

```css
p>span { display:inline-block; }

.farleft::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
}


/* these are just for the demo so it's easier to see what's going on */
p { width: 50% } 
.farleft { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

With current CSS it's impossible to capitalize the first word of each wrapped line, so we'll have to use JavaScript.
Here is a modern JS solution as opposed to relying on something like jQuery (Updated on mousemove for this example which I don't recommend for performance):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach((paragraph) => wordsToSpans(paragraph))
document.onmousemove = updateLeftmostSpans
updateLeftmostSpans()

function wordsToSpans(element) {
  element.innerHTML = element.innerText.split(" ").map(word => `<span>${word}</span>`).join(" ")
}

function updateLeftmostSpans() {
  document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach((paragraph) => {
    paragraph.querySelectorAll("span").forEach((word) => {
      word.classList.remove("leftmost")
      if (word.getBoundingClientRect().left == paragraph.getBoundingClientRect().left) word.classList.add("leftmost")
    })
  })
}
```

```css
p>span {
  display: inline block;
}

.leftmost {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.resizable {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 16rem;
  min-width: min-content;
  height: 9rem;
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: both;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<article class="resizable">
  <p>You can resize this example in the bottom right corner to see how capitalisation adapts to the paragraph dimensions.</p>
</article>
```

P.S. The closest you can get with just CSS is by using [text-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) to capitalize each word
i.e. `text-transform: uppercase;`